# azure blob container restrict file upload only from my server ip

Tags: c#, azure, blob, storage

The storage account networking setting is "Enabled from selected virtual networks and IP addresses" because we want to restrict the file upload only from our website. But we have put our server inbound and outbound ip address to the storage account Firewall list, we still get not authorize when call the api to upload the files.

I am wondering if this is a good practice or if there is a better way to restrict the access only from our website?

[storage setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wq6iL.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I would need more information to be sure but if you have verified that you have placed the correct IP's in the storage account firewalls then it is possible you have do not have the appropriate RBAC permissions to write to the storage account.

Storage accounts have their own built in RBAC roles. You need to have at least the 'Storage Blob Data Contributor' role to write to the storage account.

You can see all the RBAC roles available [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles).